# A non-serializable value was detected in the state using redux toolkit and JSON data

Tags: json, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to return some data from my db and then insert it into my front end state with `redux toolkit`, it was working fine for some dummy data structured as an array of objects.

Now I am getting the data from my db via an api it is not working. I am getting this error message:

```
A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `word.preppedWord.0.$$typeof`. Value: Symbol(react.element) 
Take a look at the reducer(s) handling this action type: word/checkMorphemes.
```

Is it because I am returning my database data with `res.json`? I am unsure of the proper way to return the data if so.

Here is my code:

```
const wordSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'word',
  initialState: { word: '', preppedWord: '' },
  reducers: {
    setWord(state, action) {
      state.word = action.payload
    },
    checkMorphemes(state, action) {
      state.preppedWord = decoder.morphemeCheck2(state.word)
    },
   [...]
})
```

```
export const morphemeCheck2 = (word) => {
  console.log(word)
  return word.split(' ').map((word, i) => {
    console.log(word)
    return (
      <span key={i}>
        <span>{prefixCheck(word)}</span>
        <span>{baseWord(word)}</span>
        <span>{suffixCheck(word)}</span>
      </span>
    )
  })
}

const prefixCheck = (x) => {
  api.getPrefixes().then((data) => {
    let prefixes = data
    for (let p = 0; p < prefixes.length; p++) {
      let prefix = prefixes[p].affix_name
      if (x.startsWith(prefix)) {
        return (
          <span className={'suffix ' + prefix} onMouseOver={() => {}}>
            {prefix}
          </span>
        )
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Here is the api route:

```
router.get('/prefixes', (req, res) => {
  db.getPrefixes()
    .then((result) => {
      res.json(result)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(`There is an error here: ${err.message}`)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing a React element in your state here - that should not be stored in state. You should create the React element when rendering and only store the `word` itself in Redux.

Comment: Thanks for the response - just to clarify is the issue that I am trying to store spans in the state?

Comment: Yes. Spans are not data. Redux is meant for data, React is meant for rendering. Store the text in Redux and render it into a span in React.